# Do Views affect performance?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list-view, performance, indexed-column

Whenever it comes to Views in SharePoint (2013 or above), the documentation offers it as a way to get around limitations (usually 5000 elements).

I currently use CSOM to **retrieve** data from SharePoint (Office365) lists. (So I only care about Select here). And is really slow, even on small Lists. Or to put it in other words: If Data Storage is Marines, SharePoint-Lists seem to be Private Pyle.

I created Indices and Views to speed up performance but cannot really see any measurable effect. Is there any performance effect at all or is it really just to get around limitations?

Has anyone ever made any measurements to track the performance boost using views and/or indexes in SharePoint-Lists?

(Additional Info):

I use Caml Queries containing only the Fields (and conditions) I need and fire them using `listname.GetItems(query)`

Comment: Another note, you are using Include to just retrieve the metadata/fields you need?

Comment: Yes. Updated my question to state that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think additional overhead of an index and multiple indices don’t give you additional performance gain
**

**Example**

For every defined index, SharePoint stores the index value for every list item in a separate table.

Having a list with let’s say 50000 items means that we have 50000 rows in AllUserData and 50000 additional rows in the NameValuePair table.

So  every time you update your list – NameValuePair need to be updated as well.

Comment: I am aware of that. An index usually slows down inserts/updates but should increase a Select performance. I only care about Select here. And in the SQL - world you can boost performance a lot by choosing the right keys and indices

Comment: Yes using SharePoint indices will definitely speed up selective access to items stored in large lists or when the overall numbers of items in your content database is high.